# How to pass argparse command line arguments to python file in azure data factory

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have a wheel file in which there are multiple packages. I have a python script main.py, outside the wheel, which contains only 2 lines of code as below

```
main.py
+++++++
from pkgname import modulename
modulename.func_name()
```

func_name() in the wheel file expects command line arguments using argparse library. If I pass command line arguments from pycharm, the code is running absolutely fine.

Now, I want to use this wheel and main.py in my adf pipeline and I expect it to work like it is working in pycharm. I have created a databricks python activity. I am providing the python script name, which is placed in the dbfs location and also the wheel file, which is placed in the dbfs location. In place of parameters for this activity, I am providing the command line arguments and triggering the adf pipeline. Yet, it is failing with the following error

```
usage: tmpvkq1uhhu.py [-h] --config_id  [--re_run_id] [--storage_account] [--client_id] [--tenant_id] [--container_name] --execution_platform  --file_system  [--vault_or_scope_name] [--secret_key] --auth_mech_class_name
tmpvkq1uhhu.py: error: the following arguments are required: --config_id, --execution_platform, --file_system, --auth_mech_class_name
```

The documentation says that parameters are the command line arguments provided to the python script which is an Array of strings.

In ADF, under databricks python activity's parameter section, I have specified like below:

```
"--config_id 10","--container_name democontainer", .......

"--config_id", "10","--container_name", "democontainer", ........

["--config_id 10","--container_name democontainer", .......]

["--config_id", "10","--container_name", "democontainer", ........]

--config_id 10, --container_name, democontainer, ........

[--config_id 10, --container_name, democontainer, ........]
```

None of the above seems to work. I still get the error even after passing the command line arguments. Can you help me with the exact format of passing the command line arguments to python script in databricks python activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps to get the required output. I have used the following code as my python script.

```
import sys
 
# total arguments
n = len(sys.argv)
print("Total arguments passed:", n)
print(sys.argv)
```

- The above code would print the number of arguments and the argument list. This file is located in `dbfs:/FileStore/main.py` of my databricks workspace.
- Now, in order to pass the arguments, we use `Parameters` section. I have passed 3 arguments `10,20 and 30` by creating new parameter for each of the value.

[image]

- When I debug the pipeline, it would successfully run and when I monitor the file run output it would be as shown below:

[image]

> The documentation says that parameters are the command line arguments provided to the python script which is an Array of strings.

- This is while using the pipeline JSON to specify the values. For the above pipeline that I used for demo, it would be as shown below:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Python1",
                "type": "DatabricksSparkPython",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "pythonFile": "dbfs:/FileStore/main.py",
                    "parameters": [
                        "10",
                        "20",
                        "30"
                    ]
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "AzureDatabricks1",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

[image]